# gradle task to run tests multiple time

Tags: testing, gradle

I want to create gradle task to run all tests multiple times, under different set of system properties.
e.g. there is system property for buffersize, i want to run all tests multiple times for different settings of buffersize.

Comment: It's better if tests are not depend on environment, but set proper environment. Such tests will produce repeatable results. Is it possible to set up system properties in @Before methods? In this case each subclass of test class can define different system properties. Another benefit - test reports will be more accurate.

Comment: @al_l_ex, but i am supposed to do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task one( type: Test ) {
  systemProperty 'some.prop', 'one'
}

task two( type: Test ) {
  systemProperty 'some.prop', 'two'
}

task main( dependsOn: [one, two] ) {
}
```

src/test/java/MyTest.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println( System.getProperty( "some.prop" ) );
  }
}
```

> gradle main --info

```
....
MyTest > test STANDARD_OUT
one
....
MyTest > test STANDARD_OUT
two
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out, another issue is, when any unit test fails in task "one", it'll show build unsuccessful and won't continue to task "two". I think they provided continue execuction in gradle 2.12RC with "--continue" keyword to keep executing, in case of test fails.  I don't know whether it'll be okay to use RC or not.

Comment: Try ignoreFailures option: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:ignoreFailures